# Roteamento Vue Js

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, aplicação-web, vue.js, vuetify

Estou criando mais de uma rota em Vue js, porém, para qualquer rota informada é redirecionada a de Login.

> router.js

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Router from 'vue-router'
import Login from '@/components/Login'
import Cadastro from '@/components/Cadastro'

Vue.use(Router)

export default new Router({
routes: [
{
  path: '/',
  name: 'Login',
  component: Login
},
{
  path: '/cadastro',
  name: 'Cadastro',
  component: Cadastro
}


]
})
```

main.js

```
// The Vue build version to load with the `import` command
// (runtime-only or standalone) has been set in webpack.base.conf with an alias.
import Vue from 'vue'
import App from './App'
import router from './router'

Vue.config.productionTip = false

/* eslint-disable no-new */
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  router,
  components: { App },
  template: '<App/>'
})
```

A rota de cadastro, por exemplo, abre o Login.

Comment: Acredito este ser o **routes.js** e como está o **main.js**?

Comment: Atualizei com o main.js, agora.

Comment: Coloque o nome da classe de **router** para **Router** no arquivo `main.js` e nele tbm importe o **VueRouter** e declare-o assim **`Vue.use(VueRouter);`**

Answer (score 2):

Você deve tirar `Vue.use(Router)` do arquivo router.js e utilizá-lo no arquivo main.js antes do new Vue. Eu também não utilizaria o new Router no router.js.

Eu deixaria assim:

Router.js

```
import Login from '@/components/Login'
import Cadastro from '@/components/Cadastro'

const routes = [
  {
    path: '/',
    name: 'Login',
    component: Login
  },
  {
    path: '/cadastro',
    name: 'Cadastro',
    component: Cadastro
  }
]

export default routes
```

main.js

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import App from './App'
import routes from './router'
import VueRouter from 'vue-router'

Vue.config.productionTip = false
Vue.use(VueRouter)

const router = new VueRouter({
  routes,
  mode: 'history'
})

/* eslint-disable no-new */
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  router,
  components: { App },
  template: '<App/>'
})
```

Answer (score -3):

Se você não criou sua app através do VUE CLI, indicado criar um arquivo main.js e efetuar o import das rotas nele.
Ali tu irá conseguir importar o VueRouter e fazer referencia através do Vue.use(....)